# What is the proper way to retrieve data from a database in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm attempting to complete the [Laravel 8 From Scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch/episodes/10) video tutorial and they **seem** (yes, I know he's probably not and I'm just not comprehending it) to skip over how they actually get data from the database.

In my case I have database table called **Pages** and in it is the field **Title**. I'm simply trying to retrieve that.

Without the defined variable this code outputs an `Undefined` error, as expected. `{{ $page->updated_at }}`

Could someone point me to the Laravel 8 documentation that explains exactly how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: You can even use raw queries. But with laravel based on your requirement its better to use https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent. Do you have ```updated_at``` in you DB table ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know I could use a vanilla PHP query, but I'm trying to do things "the Laravel way". Yes, there is an "updated_at" field.

Comment: laravel way is Eloquent . It describe the link I shared

Comment: Where is your code that you retrieve `pages` table data?

Comment: In your question you refer to `title` and `updated_at`. It would be worth making an [edit] to your question to include all relevant code, along with a screenshot of your `pages` table (and/or your Laravel migrations if you're using them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your laracast link goes to the cache video, not sure that was your intent.

Without using a model you can try accessing the database table directly from your Controller.

PagesController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class PagesController  extends Controller
{

public function index(){

    $data = DB::table('pages')->first(); // get the first row

return view('index', compact('data')); // pass $data to the view
}
}
```

index.blade.php

```
<div>{{ $data->title }}</div>
<div>{{ $data->updated_at }}</div>
```

This is a basic example of getting data from the table and passing it to a view. Once you master that, start using Eloquent Models

Comment: Thank you this answered several questions on this topic for me.